# newsiamthm without a sibling?

Tags: numbering, amsmath, theorems, amsthm

I am using the SIAM Latex template, and I wanted to create a thm-like environment which has distinct numbering from all the other tho-like environments (which are all siblings by default).

I cannot figure out how to "remove" thm as a sibling of my definition, and I cannot find any explanation of how to do this in the official [SIAM Guide](https://epubs.siam.org/pb-assets/macros/online/docsiamonline-1649270034847.pdf).

Concretely, I would like to fix this block of code to get the behaviour I want, and I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this modification.

```
\newsiamthm{puzzle}{Puzzle}
\renewcommand*\thepuzzle{\Roman{puzzle}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\newsiamthm` is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\newsiamthm}[2]{
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\sc}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\itshape}
  \theoremseparator{.}
  \theoremsymbol{}
  \newtheorem{#1}[theorem]{#2}
}
```

which means every theorem like environment defined with this command does not have a counter of its own, its using using a counter called `theorem` (or to be more precise `\c@theorem`).

If you want to have the same format for your puzzle environment, but with an independent counter, create your own macro, as of the following:

```
\newcommand{\newindthm}[2]{
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\sc}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\itshape}
  \theoremseparator{.}
  \theoremsymbol{}
  \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
}
```

and now you can use it as `\newindthm{puzzle}{Puzzle}`.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{siamart220329}

\newcommand{\newindthm}[2]{
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\sc}
    \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\itshape}
    \theoremseparator{.}
    \theoremsymbol{}
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
}

\newindthm{puzzle}{Puzzle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        Test
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{puzzle}
        Test
    \end{puzzle}
\end{document}
```

Which has the following output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For giving me working code and also explaining why I would need to do it this way :)

Comment: @SidJain you are welcome!